# Statistical Data Analysis related to Patients data

Tags: r

Hi I want to analyze the patients related data which includes fields like age, gender, mortality, medication, diagnosis etc. I am not able to decide an objective to do this. I want to come up with solutions which will help the hospitals in reducing for example the death rate or the no of patients falling from the bed. Or may be utilize the medications stock in a better way. Could you let me know how to begin with. Can I do the analysis in R?

Comment: @Bernhard gives excellent advice. At the same time, and as is he clearly signals,  this is far too broad to be  a good question here.

Comment: If you are dealing with peoples' lives then I think your employers need to pay for a local statistician and not rely on advice from strangers on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

You must realize that there is much money spent in medicine. Hospitals are usually large businesses so they can afford smart people to lead the business. Medicine attracts smart people, so a large number of really smart people have thought a lot about how to reduce death rates and accidents and using medication. Do not expect anybody around a hospital to be impressed just because you use a computer or R or statistics or machine learning.

Then, on the other side, yes: Smart people in hospitals do good things with computers, including with R. Learning about statistics, about machine learning and about R would be a good first step, aside from learning about economics, nursing and medicine, to go in the direction you aspire.

A good introduction to R is the book by Andy Field and colleagues. If you type "bioinformatics" into Amazon, you will see that there is lots of information to be soaked up. The best advice will surely be: Lay a good foundation, i.e., learn your math, learn your Frequentist as well as Bayesian statistics, learn as much as you can about the field you are investigating. You cannot know beforehand which part of math will be important for your work later.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am from Stats background. However I am facing difficulties to decide an objective into medicine and as to how I plan this work as Medicine is really vast. I have already started with R programming. Not very well versed but in a learning phase.

Comment: If you need more precise answers, you should try to ask a more precise question. Overly broad questions and those that are overly opinion based are usually closed on Cross Validated.